# How to redirect with conditions through Javscript or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Non-removable credit link

Hi,
Suppose I have an HTML template and I want to share it for free i.e. the user can download it for free from my website but they should not remove the footer credit link. If they remove the footer credit from the template they should be redirected to my website.

I found the below code on Stackoverflow

```
<div id="credits">  
<a id="creditlink" href="http://www.example.com">Site name</a>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //Let's first setup the redirect
        function redirect(){
            window.location.assign('http://www.example.com');
        }

            //which things we got to check
        function check(){
                if($('#credits').length === 0){
                    redirect();
                }

                else if($('#creditlink').length === 0){
                    redirect();
                }

                else if($("#creditlink").attr("href") !== "http://www.example.com"){
                    redirect();
                }

                else if($('#creditlink').text() !== "Site name"){
                    redirect();
                } 
            }
        //execute the function on page load
        check();
        //excute the function at the intervals of 5 seconds.
        setInterval(function () {check()}, 5000);
        });
```

The above code is lacking one thing that is it will not redirect when the user hide the div or link with CSS properties such as

```
#credits, #creditlink{
   display:none;
   visibility:hidden;
   opacity:0;
}
```

So, I want to add another condition in the code that if user tries to remove the div or link with CSS properties he should be redirected.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: I am not clear on what you are asking.  You want people to be redirected to a website if they remove a div from your website?  How would they go about doing that?

Comment: If a user is able to manipulate your website in this way, they will also be able to suppress the redirection. After your website has been loaded by a browser, you cannot prevent tech-savvy users from manipulating it. You can only prevent manipulation on your _server_, but never on a user's _browser_.

Comment: @FiniteLooper yes when user remove the div or hide it through CSS..it should redirect to the  say https://www.example.com. Basically, I want to use it in my template that user can download free from my website but when they remove the credit link from template, they should redirect to my website in this case https://www.example.com

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible to do, and it might be a little pointless even if it is possible.  You are going to add code to redirect if they hide or remove a link that credits you.  Well, if they have your template downloaded then they can just remove your link AND the code that does this checking.

Comment: Nothing you can do in this regard can't be prevented in the same way that you accomplish it.

Comment: I have updated the question please check now

Comment: If someone removes the part you don't want them to, they'll also remove anything that will redirect visitors.

Comment: With the [Mutation Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) you can monitor changes on elements, like changes in attributes, added and/or removed nodes, etc. But like the others suggest, there is no way of stopping anyone from modifying the code of the template. If anything it might hurt their experience with your templates. You can always ask nicely if someone is willing to leave the credits on the page or support you in another way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check with jQuery if some div is visible or not:

```js
$('#credits').is(":visible")
```